# Time complexity in loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Im new with algorithmic analysis. I just want to verify mi understanding:

For example:

```
for (i=0, i<n; i++) {
}
```

Is clear that there are 1 asignation, n comparations, and n incrementations.

The n function is: T(n) = t0 + t1*n + t2*n = t0 + (t1+t2)n = c0+c1*n

So the complexity is: O(n)

But, in this other cases i need some advice:

```
for (i=0, i<=n; i++) {
}
```

T(n) = t0 + t1*(n+1) + t2*(n+1) ???

```
for (i=0, i<n-1; i++) {
}
```

T(n) = t0 + t1*(n-1) + t2*(n-1) ???

```
for (i=1, i<n; i++) {
}
```

T(n) = t0 + t1*(n-1) + t2*(n-1) ???

I think one would say all those fors loops are just O(n) and thats the only thing that matters. But i want to know if those T(n) definitions are ok.

Comment: Shouldn't the first `T` equation wrong ? It should be `T(n) = t0 + t1*(n+1) + t2*n` because after the last iteration, the condition `i<n` is evaluated. So it gets executed `n+1` times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are all O(n), and yes, your equations for `T` are correct.

In general, while `T` is useful for getting familiar with complexity analysis, it's not used otherwise. Most people are concerned with the `O` of a problem. Furthermore, once you find a set of algorithms with minimal (or optimal) `O`, the problem of finding the best from that set rarely hinges on `T`. This is because things like, say, cache coherency usually matter way more than the absolute number of comparisons or additions for most practical problems.

If you take two loops:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {}
```

and

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {}
```

The bottom loop will execute one more time than the top one (it will execute when `i == n`, whereas the top loop will skip this). So when computing the run-time, these are different. The top-one will execute the comparison/increment `n` times exactly (when `i` is `{0,1,...,n-1}`) ; the bottom will execute it `n+1` (when `i` is `{0,1,...,n-1,n}`).

However, in Big-O notation, you're looking for *asymptotic behavior* - i.e. what happens with `n` is really large. And in that case, you only take the factor of `n` that varies the fastest. When `n` is very large, the extra iteration of the loop above won't matter much at all, so both loops are `O(n)`.

One key thing to keep in mind with Big-O notation is that it most definitely does not capture everything about an algorithm. It's a good first-pass check - an algorithm that is `O(n)` is almost always going to be better than one that is `O(n^3)`. But within the space of algorithms with the same - or almost the same - exponent, there can be wildly different performance when implemented on real systems.

Comment: Is a little tricky sometimes. So:  "i<n" means: 0....n-1=O(n), but "i<=n" means: 0....n=O(n+1). Im right?, or is exactly the opposite?

Comment: I am new in this concept. It is soo much confusing for me. In for(i = 0; i<n; i++) Assign i to 0 (cost 1). Compare i with n (also cost 1). Then n++ which is equal to n=n+1 (cost 2). Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

O(n) means that there is constant M>0 that the number of operation is < M*n.

So in your case it is O(n) for the second case, we could say that it is O(n-1) but it is easier to say that it is O(n) because it is exactly the same when n ->  infinity.

n-1/n -> 1

If T(n) is the exact number of operations so you can't simplify your result