# What is the time complexity and space complexity of following code

Tags: algorithm

I want to know the time complexity of following piece of code

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        printf("hi")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Time complexity in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448632/time-complexity-in-loop)

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/

i think following link is used full for this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity is nothing but the number of instructions executed in  your program. Now, in your program you have two loops. Outer loop will iterate `i=0` to `i=N-1`, which is total of N instructions that is O(N). Since you also have a inner loop which will again iterate from `j=i+1` to `j=N-1` for each `i`.

Hence, time complexity will be `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration of the inner loop work done is a follows

1. n
2. n-1
3. n-2
4. ....
5. ...
6. 1

So total work done will be n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+...+1, which turn out to be the sum of n natural numbers i.e n*(n+1)/2 so time complexity is O(n^2). As no auxiliary space is used so space complexity is O(1)